# Numpy arrays into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have several numpy arrays x and y that I want to append to a dictionary.  For example:

```
x1=[0.0,0.1,0.2] y1=[.2,.4,.5]
x2=[0.0,0.2,0.2] y2=[.2,.9,.5]
x3=[0.0,0.1,0.5] y3=[.2,.4,.0]
```

would like:

```
result = {"x1": [0.0,0.1,0.2],
          "y1": [.2,.4,.5],
          "x2": [0.0,0.2,0.2]
          "y2": [.2,.4,.5],
          "x3": [0.0,0.1,0.2],
          "y3": [.2,.4,.0]}
```

Comment: what is wrong with `result = [{'x1': x1, 'y1': y1}, ...`?

Comment: So what's the problem? You didn't even ask something.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this you just need to add them all to the dict eg.

```
data = {"x1": x1,
        "y1": y1,
        ...}
```